# How to create a new dictionary from old one using a given mapping?

Tags: python, dictionary

What I am seeking is a Python function that seeks an old dictionary and a mapping. A new dictionary should be returned using the given mapping from the old dictionary.

```
old_dic = {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4"}
mapping_dic = {"a":"e", "c":"f", "d":"g"}
```

Hence, a new dictionary should be formed containing the keys e,f, and g. It should look like:

```
new_dic = {"e":"1", "f":"3", "g":"4"}
```

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dict comprehension:

```
{v: old_dic[k] for k,v in mapping_dic.items()}
```

outputs:

```
{'e': '1', 'f': '3', 'g': '4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work, but maybe there's a better way:

```
new_dic = dict((mapping_dic[key], val) for key, val in old_dic.items() if key in mapping_dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def numberofbagels(oldmap, trans):
    newmap = {}
    for key in oldmap:
        if key in trans:
            newmap[trans[key]] = oldmap[key]
    return newmap

old_dic = {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4"}
mapping_dic = {"a":"e", "c":"f", "d":"g"}

print "%s"%(str(numberofbagels(old_dic,mapping_dic)))
```